# vote_up in thumbs_up goes to blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the thumbs_up gem, and it seemed like I got things to work, until voting for a post did absolutely nothing. Right now, clicking on the vote for this post link leads to a blank page with the URL: localhost:3000/posts/1/vote_up

Ideally I would have this work by incrementing the number of votes for a post

**My routes file**

```
Projectmadrone::Application.routes.draw do

  #devise_for :users
  devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end

  resources :posts do
     member do
         post :vote_up
      end
     end

   root :to => 'posts#index'
 end
```

**My controller method**

```
def vote_up
    begin
       current_user.vote_for(@post = Post.find(params[:id]))
       render :nothing => true, :status => 200
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      render :nothing => true, :status => 404
    end
  end
```

**app/views/post/index.html.erb**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

 <li><%= post.content %></li>
<li><%= post.attribution %> in <%= post.neighborhood %> 
<span class="post-date"><%=time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago</span></li>
<li> <%= bucket((post.neighborhood)) %> </li> 

<li>Num votes: <%= post.votes_for %></li>

<li><%= link_to('vote this post!', vote_up_post_path(post), :method => :post) %></li>

<% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspicious:

```
render :nothing => true, :status => 200
```

Seems like that would tell the controller to render the blank page you're seeing.  Try commenting it out and see if that fixes it.  Hope that helps!

Comment: ah unfortunately that gives me a no method error: undefined method `vote_for' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @amritha - That error makes it sound like `current_user` isn't defined.  Are you sure it's been loaded, and isn't `nil`?

Comment: Try `puts "current_user:" current_user.inspect` - that'll print the value to the console (Good luck finding it amid all the other logging!).